How to bypass API that required authenication with fixture data cypress component testing in reactjs
I'm trying to bypass the api that required authenication completely with fixture data to test this component, but received this error " -click (uncaught exception) Error: No active account! Verify a user has been signed in and setActiveAccount has been called."
import React from "react";
import UpgradeGuidance from "../components/UpgradeGuidance";
import upgradeInfo from "../../cypress/fixtures/upgradeGuidanceData.json";

describe("UpgradeGuidance component", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.viewport(1024, 768);
    cy.mount(<UpgradeGuidance upgradeHref={upgradeInfo} />);
  });

  it("Check if ShortTerm Name Rendered", () => {
    cy.intercept("https://abc/foss-upgrade-guidance/", {
      fixture: "upgradeGuidanceData.json",
    }).as("upgradeInfo");
    cy.get("Button").contains("Get upgrade advice").should("exist").click();

    cy.wait("@upgradeInfo").then((interception) => {
      const upgradeInfo = interception.response?.body;
      cy.get("[data-testid='upgrade-short']").contains(
        upgradeInfo.shortTermAdvice
      );
    });
  });
});



Please post some details of the component and how it uses the authentication.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
